# LDAP/Pam: No passwd entry for user while getent passwd shows all LDAP users

Tags: login, authentication, ldap, pam

The LDAP authentication seems not working on my ubuntu 14.04.

`getent passwd` returns all the LDAP users, which means it is successfully connected to the LDAP server and see all the user information.

However, `getent passwd USERNAME` returns nothing, even though `USERNAME` is one of the LDAP users.

The error message in `/var/log/auth.log` is `No passwd entry for user USERNAME`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution.  After I restarted nscd (not nslcd), it works.